# How to get MSTest to work with Gallio/MBUnit?

Tags: mstest, teamcity, mbunit, gallio

How to get MSTest to work with Gallio/MBUnit?

I am trying to get TeamCity to work with Gallio/MBUnit and also some legacy MSTest unit tests.  The MSTest section fails with a "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" error message.

Problem seen with GallioBundle-3.1.397.0-Setup-x64.msi.

Answer (score 1):

I see many new versions are listed in the the link Jeff provided. Why aren't they listed on the Gallio website? Are that not (yet) official releases?

-EDIT-

I tried the latest version of the link Jeff provided. But still i got the same error:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

I can run the tests fine in VS ...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a known issue:
[Issue 606: Gallio disables mstest from CLI](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/issues/detail?id=606&can=1&q=mstest&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary#makechanges)

Comment: Thanks for you help Jeff.  I tried a development build and it worked fine.  In the last official release it was still a problem.   I spent a long time tracking this one down and only asked the question on SO so that others might be spared the pain 8)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in recent builds.  Try one from http://ccnet.gallio.org/Distributables/